# Joomla template background and header image

Tags: css, image, mobile, background-image, joomla3.0

I have changed the background image in my Joomla template directly in the index.php file as well as the header image.
I changed the image src.
My problem is that those 2 images are missing when I open the website on a tablet or mobile but no problem on desktop.
I have gone through everything from @media queries and cannot find the issue. please I need help! Her with the index.php code

```
<?php
/**
* Date         July  31, 2014
* Copyright    Copyright (C) 2014 10templates.com
* License  GPL
*/
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();

$this->language = $doc->language;
$this->direction = $doc->direction;

JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');

?>
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
html xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this-  >language; ?>" >
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo     $this->template ?>/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-apple-capable" content="true"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/menu.js"></script>
<!--script src="/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
 <script src="/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"></script--> 

 </head>
 <body>
 <!--main container -->
 <div class="container-fluid"> 

 <!--Begin header-->
 <div class="header">
 <div class="header-inner">
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-2" style="none" />
 <header class="jumbotron">
 <img src="http://localhost/joomla/images/utv_pics/utv_transparent.gif" style="max-width:90%">
 <!--Begin Navbar-->
 <?php if ($this->countModules('position-1')) : ?>
 <div class="nav2">
      <!--button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="nav2">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    <a class="brand" href="index.php"><?php echo $sitename ?></a>
  <div class="collapse nav-collapse" id="nav2"-->
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="none" />

  <!--End navbar-->
  <?php endif; ?>
  </header></div></div></div>

  <div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="clearfix">
  <div class="leftCont">
  </div>

  <div id="content" role="main">

  <?php if ($this->countModules('position-9')) : ?>
  <div class="banners">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-9" style="none" />
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <!-- Begin Content -->
  <div class="insider">

  <jdoc:include type="component" />
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-3" style="none" />
  </div>
  <!-- End Content -->

  </div>

  <div class="rightCont">
  <div class="clearfix">
  </div></div></div></div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <footer class="clearfix">
  <section>
  <?php if ($this->countModules('position-4')) : ?>
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-4" style="xhtml" />
  <?php endif; ?>
  </section>
  <section>
  <?php if ($this->countModules('position-5')) : ?>
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-5" style="xhtml" />
  <?php endif; ?>
  </section>
  <section>
  <?php if ($this->countModules('position-6')) : ?>
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-6" style="xhtml" />
  <?php endif; ?>

  </section>
  </footer>
 </div></div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: did i mention that I was desperate?

Answer (score 0):

You have added the local image URL:

```
<img src="http://localhost/joomla/images/utv_pics/utv_transparent.gif" style="max-width:90%">
```

As you can see that URL is pointing to localhost which is your local development workstation. That address won't work with a different device.

You should use the baseurl property instead:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/utv_pics/utv_transparent.gif" style="max-width:90%">
```

and make sure that your image utv_transparent.gif is in the images/utv_pics folder inside your current template folder.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense and I was looking in all the wrong places...I have now changed this and now I get a forbidden code: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /test/templates/acropolis3free/css/.../images/utv_pics/Toyota_image.jpg on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: I wonder if this is the same issue I am having with my bootstrap: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: The 403 issue is probably due to file permissions. Make sure that the folders and files have read permissions for the user your http server is running with. The bootstrap problem is probably a bad URL as well. Check the code above. It points to /media/jui/css folder off the root of your site. Are the files actually there?

Comment: I got all my url's working correctly and I have no more 404 error code but I still have a bootstrap-responsive error code..my site seem to be working alright though....I looked in the ftp folder and the bootstrap files are in there as per the url GET request on the Inspect error I get...So now I have NO idea where the problem is. Thank you for your help with those url's i have been searching for weeks in my @media code thinking it is a mobile problem not even realising it only works on my localhost...felt quite stupid! But thanks so much!!

Comment: What's the error code that you're getting with bootstrap? Is it something you're seeing in the developer console?

Comment: I get this error code in Chrome developer console http://www.utv-racing.co.za/test/templates/acropolis3free/js/bootstrap.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Category not found) and this code: http://www.utv-racing.co.za/test/templates/acropolis3free/css/bootstrap-responsive Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Category not found)

Comment: where's that bootstrap.min.js on the filesystem?

Comment: I checked in my ftp folder and it is in the folder as specified by that url link

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong image location that works on localhost i.e your PC only.

Instead of

```html
<img src="http://localhost/joomla/images/utv_pics/utv_transparent.gif" style="max-width:90%">
```

simply use this

```html
<img src="/images/utv_pics/utv_transparent.gif" style="max-width:90%">
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work in Chrome...not working in Firefox and bootstrap also not working...if you have any idea where my url link is wrong and where I can find ti to make correct I will appreciate it!

Comment: Did you clean your browser cache and also Joomla cache. The change I suggested will show when you clean your cache.